# Find a prime $p$ satisfying $p \equiv 1338 \mod 1115$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Find a prime $p$ satisfying $p \equiv 1338 \mod 1115$. Are there infinitely many such primes. A little confused about this problem, any help or advice?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: If $p \equiv 1338 \pmod{1115}$ then $p = 1338+1115n$ for some integer $n$.

Now, note that $1338 = 6 \cdot 223$ and $1115 = 5 \cdot 223$. Hence, $p = 223(6+5n)$.

What does this tell you about $n$?

Comment: that there is infinitely many primes numbers $p$ for $n \in Z$ ?

Comment: No, that's not quite right. Using only the condition $p \equiv 1338 \pmod{1115}$ gives us that $p$ is in the form $223(6+5n)$. However, we also know that $p$ is prime. So, can $p = 223(6+5n)$ be the product of two factors greater than $1$?

Comment: no by the definition of a prime number

Comment: thus 6 + 5n = 1 ?

Comment: @Pasie15: That's correct. From that equality, you can find out what $n$ has to be, and therefore what the prime number $p$ is using the fact that $p = 1338 + 1115n$.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is easy. Notice that $p \equiv 1338 (mod 1115)$ iif $p-0 \equiv 1338-1115 (mod 1115)$ because $1115 \equiv 0 (mod 1115)$. Also $1338-1115 = 223$ is prime.

Therefore 223 is the prime you're looking for.